# How to use Chartkick and mapping line graphs

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, chartkick

I am currently using Chartkick to make a line graph that is plotting the progress of a profit and loss chart with individual bets. Currently I have the graph correctly outputting a graph with a profit and loss while the bets are grouped by the day on which they were placed with the following code

```
<%= area_chart @bets.group(:created_at).sum(:profit_or_loss).map { |x,y| { x => (@sum += y)} }.reduce({}, :merge), xtitle: "Date", ytitle: "Units" %>
```

However I am looking to change this so that the graph plots per 50 entries or 100 entries. I am unsure of the correct syntax to group it this way as my understanding is that the id of each entry is not a class.

This is the schema for the entry database.

```
create_table "bets", force: :cascade do |t|
  t.string   "game"
  t.datetime "created_at",                            null: false
  t.datetime "updated_at",                            null: false
  t.string   "bet_placed"
  t.decimal  "profit_or_loss", default: 0.0
  t.date     "date_of_bet",    default: '2016-03-11'
  t.decimal  "odds",           default: 0.0
  t.decimal  "units_placed",   default: 0.0
  t.boolean  "push",           default: false
  t.boolean  "resolved",       default: false
  t.integer  "bookmaker"
  t.integer  "sport"
end
```

Comment: When you say "per 50 entries", do you mean you want to group 50 entries together, regardless of date, instead of grouping all entries for a given date?  Eg: 30 entries on 2016-09-04 and 80 entries on 2016-09-05 would create 3 points on the graph.

Comment: @JohnFeltz yes that is what I mean, i wish to group the entries regardless of date, but just in groups of 10 or 20.

Comment: You may not be able to do this neatly on one line - let me think about it.  You'll probably have order("created_at limit 50") in there...